# Get classes on original option to select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have the following code for a select2 dropdown. My aim is to get all the attributes from the

`<option  level="2" data-type="ci_type" value="44">Sales Service</option>` ,

on the select2 dropdown list which looks like this now

`<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable"><div class="select2-result-label"><span class="select2-match"></span> Sales Service</div></li>`

Is this possible?
During my research i found `formatResultCssClass` option , but not sure how to use this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#my_select2_dropdown").select2({

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label>Value:</label>
<select id="my_select2_dropdown"  style="">
  <option style="padding-left:0em" level="0" data-type="type" value="1">value1</option>
  <option style="padding-left:1em" level="1" data-type="type" value="2">value2</option>
  <option style="padding-left:2em" level="2" data-type="type" value="4">value3</option>
  <option style="padding-left:2em" level="2" data-type="type" value="5">value4</option>
  <option style="padding-left:1em" level="1" data-type="type" value="7">value5
</select>
```

Comment: you mean to say that on any option select event you want to fetch associated `level`, `data-type` and `style` attribute ?

Comment: Yes. I want them to appear on the select2 list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution at last. Here is the code. Do not know if this is the best option or not , but it certainly works.

```
jQuery("#myselect2dropdown option").each(function(i,e){
        jQuery("#myselect2dropdown").data('select2').dropdown.find("li:eq("+i+")").attr("data-type",jQuery(e).attr("data-type"));
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know is it possible with before select2 version 4 but it's definitely possible with select2 v4 using `templateResult`. If you are using v4 here is how to achieve that..

```
$("#cmdb_ci_type_parent_id").select2({
    templateResult: function(data, container) {
      if (data.element) {
        $(container).attr('lebel', $(data.element).attr("level"));
        $(container).attr('data-type', $(data.element).attr("data-type"));
      }
      return data.text;
    }
});
```

And this is what you get `<li>`

```
<li id="select2-cmdb_ci_type_parent_id-result-x7kd-1" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" lebel="0" data-type="ci_type">Services</li>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#cmdb_ci_type_parent_id").select2({
    templateResult: function(data, container) {
      if (data.element) {
        $(container).attr('lebel', $(data.element).attr("level"));
        $(container).attr('data-type', $(data.element).attr("data-type"));
      }
      return data.text;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<label>Value:</label>
<select id="cmdb_ci_type_parent_id" name="cmdb_ci_type[parent_id]" style="">
  <option style="padding-left:0em" level="0" data-type="ci_type" value="1">Services</option>
  <option style="padding-left:1em" level="1" data-type="ci_type" value="26">Business Service</option>
  <option style="padding-left:2em" level="2" data-type="ci_type" value="44">Sales Service</option>
  <option style="padding-left:2em" level="2" data-type="ci_type" value="45">Support Service</option>
  <option style="padding-left:1em" level="1" data-type="ci_type" value="27">IT Service</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Yes , But that is not the problem , I'm trying them to attach these same attributes to the select2 results list. That is where the issue happens.

Comment: @SoorajChandran with version 4 use can do with templateResult

Comment: Sorry , I'm using 3.5.2 version

Comment: Before version 4 templateResult not present in plugin.

Comment: @SoorajChandran check the example with v4 you can get every property of the parent select options.